# How to identify optical and acoustic branch, also longitudinal and transvers branch?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals, dispersion

I have a picture describing the dispersion relation of silicon in the first brilioun zone. I am right now confused: how to identify the optical branch and the acoustic branch, also longitudinal and transvers branch.

[image: the dispersionrelation of Silicon in the first brillioun zone]

Comment: Optic branch has energy at k=0...